# Frames to milliseconds conversion in android

Tags: android, audiotrack

In Android the [getPlaybackHeadPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getPlaybackHeadPosition%28%29)() method of [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class returns the playback head position expressed in frames ,what is its equivalent value in milli seconds?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm guessing that it would be

```
( track.getPlaybackHeadPosition( ) / track.getSampleRate( ) ) * 1000.0
```

In other words, the number of frames played divided by the number of frames per second. You then multiply the result by 1000 to get milliseconds.

A frame consists of one sample per channel and so should be equivalent to sample rate.

For example, if `getPlaybackHeadPosition( )` returns `8654` and `getSampleRate( )` returns `8000` then the time since the start of the track would be `( 8654 / 8000 ) * 1000` or `1081.75ms`. (Assuming floating point arithmetic)

Comment: for example, if the audio has 8000 samples/sec, (track.getPlaybackHeadPosition( )/8) gives you current playback head position in milli seconds.

Comment: Correct. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: So a "frame" is the same as a sample?

Comment: Or with plain integer math (no floats):  track.getPlaybackHeadPosition() * 1000 / track.getSampleRate()

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Nike is right。

But there is a problem。

If we call the `MediaExtractor.seekTo` method, `AudioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition()` returns accumulate value。

`MediaExtractor.getSampleTime() / 1000` is the right ms for current position.

You can check it out!